# Finding Whether A Point Falls in Ranges Based on Function

Tags: r, graph

So I have a graph that looks like so:
[image]

The Dotted Lines are All that I care about and I want to find whether a point (seen in the graph) falls above the green, between the green and the dark yellow or below the dark yellow. The Equations for the green and dark yellow are below:

```
hh = function(x){95 - (5*(x-6)^2)/ 1156}
mh = function(x){75 - (5*(x-6)^2)/ 1156}
```

I have a larger data set containing all those points with names to them, and i want to find the percentage a player has above the green, between the two and below the dark yellow.

Comment: You can easily determine if a point is above `hh`, below `mh`, or between the two. To compute a percentage you need to have a basis value (the denominator in the fraction). What is that?

Comment: @dcarlson it varies by player, but how would I find whether the point is above, below or in between?

Comment: You have not provided any data, but presumably you have coordinates for each of the points on your plot. The Exit_Velo is the y-axis value and the Launch_Angle is the x-axis value. You compute `hh` and `mh` from the Launch_Angle value and compare them to the Exit_Velo value.